# Change User folder default location in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

We're short of space on our server, so I would like to move all user profiles to another drive.  So I need help with the following questions:

1. How can I change the user default location? (I will Follow [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c89752b7-7d8e-4bfb-9d77-87527b5999e5/change-location-of-users-folder-in-windows-server-2008-standard?forum=winserverfiles) link).
2. How can I change existing user locations? (I have many users so need some automated batch script or any tools)

Comment: Already checked out serverfault.com/questions/472009/how-to-automatically-change-user-folders-location but not useful stuff

Answer (score 1):

1. You can configure (with a GPO) Folder redirection (as the link you posted suggests).
   Why not using it?
2. The following method is not supported by Microsoft, but it worked for me perfectly.
   You move the whole "Users" folder to the other drive, and then create a [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) in the old location.

Comment: Ok, I will try it out then let you inform. :) Thanks @EliadTech